# ggplot x axis label too long and need line break

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'trying to shorten my x axis label.

I want to change the x label with two line, with same text length

How can I shorten my text and show in two lines?

[image]

Comment: Maybe flip the coords would be better? Also please share some reprodicble data using `dput(df)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `word` to take the first few words and `str_wrap` to control the number of characters per line like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~label, ~value,
  "my_very_long_label", 10,
  "even_longer_label_with more_words", 10,
  "really_quite_verbose_label", 10
) |> 
  mutate(label = str_replace_all(label, "_", " "),
         label = word(label, 1, 3),  # Use only the first 3 words
         label = str_wrap(label, 15) # Only 15 characters per line
         ) |>  
  ggplot(aes(label, value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>